# Is relative velocity invariant under special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, invariants

If a metre stick passes an observer at speed $v$, would all observers in any inertial frame of reference say the speed of the meter stick relative to the observer is exactly $v$?

If so what is it also true for non inertial frames of reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the magnitude of three-velocity is *not* invariant. The related quantity that *is* invariant is the magnitude of the four-velocity. Four-velocity is the rate of change of four-position (spacetime-position) of an object with respect to the time measured by a clock attached to the object.

The magnitude of an object's four-velocity is always equal to $c$, the speed of light. For an object at rest (with respect to the coordinate system) its four-velocity points in the direction of the time coordinate. In contrast, the four-velocity of an object moving close to the speed of light (with respect to the coordinate system) is space-like, with a vanishing component in the time direction.

In loose terms and from a spacetime perspective, any object moves at the speed of light. Depending on the reference frame chosen this movement can be fully in the time direction (frame moving with the object), or both in time and spatial directions (any frame in which the object is not at rest).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a frame-independent concept of relative velocity. That means it's a physical concept having nothing to do with arbitrary reference frames or coordinate systems. It doesn't make sense to ask whether it's "also" invariant in noninertial frames, though you could ask whether a particular method of calculating it from frame-dependent quantities would also work in a noninertial frame.

There is a separate concept called "closing velocity" that is frame-dependent. This is simply the velocity of one of the objects minus the velocity of the other. For example, a train with speed $v$ and a beam of light heading toward each other would have a closing velocity of $v+c$ in that frame, while the ordinary relative velocity of the light relative to the train would be $c$.

Comment: This answer and the one by Muphrid come down to stating that the difference in *rapidity* is constant, and that is both true and useful but not exactly what I interpret the OP to have asked.

Comment: @dmckee: no, the relative velocity as usually defined is invariant, whether it's written $v$ or as a rapidity or as a four-vector. There is a thing called "closing velocity" which is not, but that's much less common. I know John Rennie has 97k reputation, but this answer of his is simply wrong.

Comment: I've never heard of this distinction, but won't argue about it. That said, I'll bet money that my introductory students would take the interpretation that John and I have used as the meaning they assign to "relative velocity".

Comment: @dmckee: embarrassingly I have to admit ben is correct, though in my defence I'd say it's 7 a.m. here in the UK and I haven't had my first coffee yet. I forget to subtract off $v$ to get a relative velocity. The relative velocity is still frame dependant though.

Comment: @JohnRennie I think that everyone is in agreement here about what is and is not invariant, it's just that you and I selected the very naive meaning of "relative velocity" that a beginning student would use and everyone else selected the meaning assigned those words by relativists. I'm going to add "closing velocity" to my curriculum for modern physics next time I teach it.

Answer (score 1):

No, and you can show this easily using the Lorentz transformations.

Start in our rest frame $S$, with an object passing the origin at velocity $u$. If the position of the object is $x = 0$ at time $t = 0$, then at time $t = T$ the position is just $x = uT$. So we have the pair of points $(0, 0)$ and $(T, uT)$.

Now look at this from the frame $S'$ moving at velocity $v$ relative to $S$, and let's calculate the velocity of the object, $u'$,  in $S'$. The Lorentz transformations tell us:

$$\begin{align}
t' &= \gamma \left( t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right) \\
x' &= \gamma \left( x- vt \right)
\end{align}$$

If we take the origins of $S$ and $S'$ to coincide then the point $(0, 0)$ is the same in both frames, so we just need to find out where $(T, uT)$ is in S'. Substituting into the Lorentz transformations we get:

$$\begin{align}
t' &= \gamma \left( T - \frac{vuT}{c^2}\right) \\
x' &= \gamma \left( uT - vT \right)
\end{align}$$

And the velocity $u'$ is just given by $u' = x'/t'$ so:

$$\begin{align}
u' &= \frac{\gamma \left( uT - vT \right)}{\gamma \left( T - \frac{vuT}{c^2}\right)} \\
   &= \frac{u - v}{1 - \frac{vu}{c^2}}
\end{align}$$

The relative velocity of the object and $S$ is then just:

$$\begin{align}
 u'_{rel} &= u' - (-v) \\
          &= \frac{u - v}{1 - \frac{vu}{c^2}} + v \\
          &= \frac{u - v^2u/c^2}{1 - vu/c^2}
\end{align}$$

So the relative velocity of S and the object is not the same for all observers.

Comment: You seem to be interpreting the question as whether an object with a given velocity in one inertial frame has that same velocity in every inertial frame. I think that probably isn't the intended question, because even in Newtonian physics that obviously wouldn't be true. I think "the observer" is the same observer as "an observer" but different from "all observers".

Comment: @benrg: the question is about a given **relative** velocity, and in Newtonian physics that is the same in every frame. As I've shown, in SR it isn't.

Comment: I asked this question as I was solving a problem where a metre stick passes an observer at 0.1c. I solved this by finding the length contraction of the stick and then using $t=\frac{d}{v}$. In this I just used 0.1c and got the right answer. For questions like this do we use the velocity that the person measuring the time would measure?

Comment: @JohnRennie: Which relative velocity? $(u-v)/(1-uv)$ is the relative velocity of the object and $S'$, not the relative velocity of the object and $S$ as measured in $S'$. Its Newtonian $c\to\infty$ limit is $u-v$, not $u$ or $v$.

Comment: @Joseph To make this obvious consider an observer to whom you appear to be going 0.95c in the direction of the rulers motion. To that observer the ruler must still have a velocity less than c and therefore be faster than you by not more than 0.05c. So relative velocity is not invariant. However there is a related quantity called "[rapidity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity)" which has several useful properties one of which is that differences in rapidity *are* invariant.

Comment: @benrg: oops, yes, thanks :-) That'll teach me to attempt answers before the first coffee of the morning.

Comment: @JohnRennie, your new answer is the closing velocity, not what is normally called the relative velocity. The relative velocity would be $u'$ and $v$ combined with the velocity addition formula (which equals $u$). This matches [the definition in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity) and every textbook I can remember seeing. In fact introductory SR courses make a big point of the fact that the relative velocity is not the vector difference of the velocities—that's how they introduce the velocity addition formula, as the correct way to compute relative velocities.

Comment: @benrg: if the velocity of the object in $S'$ is $u'$ and the velocity of $S$ in $S'$ is $v$, then isn't the relative velocity of the two in $S'$ just $u' - v$? This seems to me to be the obvious interpretation of the phrase *relative velocity*. If you use the relativistic addition in $S'$ then of course you're going to get back $u$.

Comment: @JohnRennie: It is definitely called the "closing velocity", at least when used of two objects on a collision course. I don't think I've ever seen it called the "relative velocity". If you can find a counterexample then I'd definitely like to see it. As I said, the velocity addition formula is introduced as the correct way to calculate relative velocities. If relative velocities are closing velocities, then what should we say the velocity addition formula calculates?

Comment: @benrg: your interpretation of the question would make it "If a metre stick passes an observer at speed v **in frame S**, would all observers in any inertial frame of reference say the speed of the meter stick relative to the observer is v **in frame S**". OK, that's a valid interpretation, but it doesn't make for a terribly interesting question.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Not "the speed relative to the observer in frame S", just "the speed relative to the observer". The observer is at rest in frame S. The velocity of X relative to Y is the velocity of X in the rest frame of Y. It is universally defined that way as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can think of this geometrically.  In Euclidean space, the angle between two vectors is rotationally invariant.  In Minkowski space, the same applies with respect to Lorentz transformations.  Here, the "angle" is the "relative rapidity" between two different timelike vectors.

Expiclitly, we have $a \cdot b = |a| |b| \cosh \varphi$ for $\varphi$ the relative rapidity.  This inner product is a Lorentz scalar and thus invariant with respect to the Lorentz transformation.  The magnitudes $|a|$ and $|b|$ are also Lorentz invariants, so $\cosh \varphi$ must be Lorentz invariant, and therefore $\varphi$ is Lorentz invariant.  Note that $\cosh \varphi = \gamma$ and $\sinh \varphi = \gamma \beta$.

An observer following one of the timelike vectors will perceive an object following the other timelike vector as having a velocity determined by that relative rapidity.  All other inertial frames agree on what that relative rapidity is (because of LT invariance of the relative rapidity), so there is no ambiguity.